# "warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast" there is no pointer

Tags: pointers, integer, warnings

The warning "warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast" is appearing in the line:

`for (lin = lin_inicial; lin < (lin_inicial + num_linhas); lin++)`

`lin` is declared as `int lin;`.
`lin_inicial` and `num_linhas` are passed to the function like this:
`void mult_matriz (int linha_inicial, int num_linhas)`

Someone knows why the compiler is warning me about integer and pointer when there is no pointer?

Comment: In which language? Also, is `mult_matriz` perhaps being passed a pointer?

Comment: `lin_inicial` is not the same identifier as `linha_inicial`. Can you post the code so we can see what what is?

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem. It was a ctrl+C, ctrl+v problem. I never find those problems. Sory to bother.